# mouse cursor position in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I get cursor X and Y in javascript?

```
var $curX=(ns6)?e.pageX : event.clientX+ietruebody().scrollLeft;
var $curY=(ns6)?e.pageY : event.clientY+ietruebody().scrollTop;
```

I had found this two, but they appear as "undefined". Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a good rule-of-thumb that any page with advice on how to deal with Netscape 6 is probably pretty old and therefore suspect. (Actually, if it's *not* old it's probably even more suspect!)

Answer (score 12):

I assume you don't want a framework answer. If not, try this:

```
document.onclick=function(evt) {
    evt = (evt || event);
    alert(evt.clientX + ' ' + evt.clientY);
}
```

I wasn't sure what event you wanted, so I just used an `onclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

*The accepted tutorial only link answer points to a broken link. For people coming by searching here*

---

Check out the [jquery mousemove api](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/).

You can use the above as

```
$("#SomeTag").mousemove(function(event) {
  var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
  msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
  $("#SomeDisplayTag").append("<div>" + msg + "</div>");
});
```