# How can I get cursor coordinate?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get cursor coordinate from `asp.net c#` in all page `<div>` area and send to `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Are you looking for the coordinates of the mouse cursor? If so, JavaScript may be more appropriate than trying to post-back to a server-side control.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you want the mouse cursor position, you can do this using javascript.

Check out

- [JavaScript Cursor Position](http://hartshorne.ca/2006/01/23/javascript_cursor_position/)
- [mouse cursor position in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248785/mouse-cursor-position-in-javascript)

#### Update

If you want to use jQuery you can do this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      $('#TextBox1').val(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
<asp:TextBox id="tbx" runat="server" onchange="javascript:GetCursoCoordinate(this)"/>

function GetCursoCoordinate(textbox) 
{
    textbox = textbox || window.event;
    var result= {x:0, y:0};
    if (textbox.pageX || textbox.pageY) 
    {
        result.x = textbox.pageX;
        result.y = textbox.pageY;
    } 
    else 
    {
        var a = document.documentElement;
        var b = document.body;
        result.x = textbox.clientX + (a.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft) - (a.clientLeft || 0);
        result.y = textbox.clientY + (a.scrollTop || b.scrollTop) - (a.clientTop || 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, getting the cursor position is easy. Simply [read this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position) and it explains everything. It also has a live example showing you an example.

Comment: is nice but how i cant send to <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>